# ValueError: could not convert string to float in pandas when using astype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

so this is the line that is getting the error :

```
footballers['Value (M)'] = footballers['Value (M)'].astype(float)
```

where the footballers[] is defined as:

```
    footballers = df.copy()
footballers['Unit'] = df['Value'].str[-1]
footballers['Value (M)'] = np.where(footballers['Unit'] == '0', 0, 
                                    footballers['Value'].str[1:-1].replace(r'[a-zA-Z]',''))
footballers['Value (M)'] = footballers['Value (M)'].str[1:-1].astype(float)

footballers['Value (M)'] = np.where(footballers['Unit'] == 'M', 
                                    footballers['Value (M)'], 
                                    footballers['Value (M)']/1000)
footballers = footballers.assign(Value=footballers['Value (M)'],
                                 Position=footballers['Preferred Positions'].str.split().str[0])
```

The error which i am getting is :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

this is row -
[image]

Comment: If your footballers['Unit'] == '0' is false, then you will footballers['Value'].str[1:-1].replace(r'[a-zA-Z]','').  This does not give you a value that can be astype to float.  Did you see what's in the dataframe after doing np.where ?

Answer (score 0):

If your leading and trailing characters `footballers['Value'].str[0]` and `footballers['Value'].str[-1]` are not digits, the conversion to `float` will fail.

Try:

```
footballers['Value (M)'] = footballers['Value (M)'].str.extractall(r'([\d\.]+)') \
                                                   .astype(float)
```

If this fails again, try to find bad rows

```
footballers.loc[pd.to_numeric(footballers['Value (M)'], errors='coerce').isna(),
                'Value (M)']
```

Comment: I have attached the image now.

Comment: Where is the column `Value (M)`? Please update your post with the output of `print(footballers.head().to_string(index=False))`

Comment: corrected now :)

Comment: Try: `df['Values'].str.extractall(r'([\d\.]+)')`

Comment: it is giving me the keyerror -> KeyError: 'Values'

Comment: I mean `footballers['Value (M)'].str.extractall(r'([\d\.]+)')`